# Binding IBM SQL Database with ASP.NET 5 in Bluemix

Tags: db2, odbc, asp.net-core, ibm-cloud

I'm creating an application in ASP.NET 5 and need to deploy the same in Bluemix. I would want to connect to IBM SQL Database in Bluemix.
I'm trying to use ODBC to connect to IBM SQL Database. But, when I build my application in Visual Studio 2015, it throws compiler error.

[This is the error that I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWrF8.jpg)

> The type or namespace name 'Odbc' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Visual Studio shows that the System.Data.Odbc is available in DNX 4.5.1 but unavailable in DNX Core 5.0 and hence it throws the error.

I'm stuck and unable to proceed further.
What should I do to be able to use the ODBC connection?

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Even if you resolve the System.Data.Odbc error, connecting to the SQL Database (DB2) does not currently work from an ASP.NET 5 app running on Linux (as it would be in Bluemix).

Comment: Ok. So, which database could I connect to from an ASP.NET application running in Bluemix?

Comment: For a relational database there isn't a good option right now. You would have to use something like MS SQL Server running on a SoftLayer VM or somewhere outside Bluemix.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please guide me to any tutorial to achieve the same? Would be of immense help.

Comment: This might help http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html. The connection string could be changed to point to the remote database.

Comment: Thanks...So, if I create an MS SQL Database in Azure and connect an ASP.NET application running in Bluemix, the application would work fine?

Comment: Yes I have done that. The only issue is with the IP whitelist in Azure, you don't know what your Bluemix app's IP is going to be so you have to allow a large range.

Comment: Thanks @opiethehokie for all your support.

I switched to Cloudant NoSQL DB and its working like a charm...

Comment: I recently tried the ElephantSQL service and that worked as well.